# How to access and store list from firebase in android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
List<String> userinterest=new ArrayList<String>();
FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId=user.getUid();
    
public void UserInterest() {
    
    myRef.child("users");
    myRef.child(userId);
    myRef.child("userinterest");
    myRef.child("list").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.d("list", snapshot.child("list").getValue().toString());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
        }
    });
}
```

I tried this code But I am getting a fatal exception.
I want the List of data and store that in an ArrayList. someone please help me with this how to access the list of user interests.

from this

```
users
     LMECILdKstfD1kgmtMQv6wOswxa2
     email:"shetyheef@gmail.com"
     password:"qwerty"

     userinterest
        list
           0:"I Will agree to use personal interest"
           1:"General_mix"
           2:"Technolgy"
           3:"Sports"
           4:"Science"
           5:"Maths"
```

Comment: "iam getting fatal exception" Please edit your question (there's an `edit` link right under it) to show the exact message you get and its stack trace.

Comment: If you're interested in reading/storing lists in the Realtime Database, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/@alex.mamo/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-realtime-database-to-a-list-of-objects-53f27b33c8f3) will help.

Answer (score 2):

The first 3 lines of this code do nothing:

```
myRef.child("users");
myRef.child(userId);
myRef.child("userinterest");
myRef.child("list").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

The `child(...)` method returns a new `DatabaseReference` object, and since you're not assigning that, the first three lines are meaningless.

If you want to read from the `/users/$userId/userinterest/list` path, do:

```
myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("userinterest/list")
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

---

In addition: never leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring possible errors. At its minimum, it should be:

```
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
  throw databaseError.toException(); 
}
```